# What is the mean `string & number & boolean`?

Tags: typescript, types

```
interface T3 {
  func(arg: number): void;
  func(arg: string): void;
  func(arg: boolean): void;
}

class T3Class2 implements T3 {
  func(name: string | number | boolean) { 
  }
} // pass
class T3Class3 implements T3 {
  func(name: string & number & boolean) {
  }
} // pass
```

The T3Class3 implement T3  why vscode not error tip?

I understand the `string & number & boolean` no intersection part, so this is an error.

Comment: Class method parameters are checked [bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) in TypeScript; this is unsafe but sometimes useful.  `string & number & boolean` doesn't "mean" anything, it's equivalent to `never`.  The reason `func(name: never){}` doesn't complain is because of bivariance (since `never` is assignable to all types, including `string | number | boolean`).   Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why VSCode does not show an error in the T3Class3 implementation is that TypeScript allows empty types in certain cases. In the case of function parameters, an empty type essentially means that the function expects no valid arguments. This can be useful in situations where you want to define a placeholder or a stub implementation for a method that you plan to implement later.

Since TypeScript does not raise an error for empty types in function parameters, the T3Class3 implementation passes the type checking. However, if you were to try to invoke the func method on an instance of T3Class3, passing any argument, TypeScript would raise an error because the intersection type string & number & boolean cannot be satisfied.

So, while TypeScript allows the implementation of T3Class3, it is important to understand that it does not provide any meaningful behavior for the func method.